# MuPDF Android- display cover page alone in the “two page view” mode in landscape orientation on tablet

Tags: android, layout, customization, mupdf

I have integrated MuPDF in my android application to show PDF in landscape mode. I need to display 2 pages on the screen except for the cover page or first page of PDF.

I have used `core.setDisplayPages(2);` to show 2 pages.

Currently it shows first page or cover page as right aligned with black patch on left as shown in [image], but i need to display it in center of the screen.

I have tried by using current page index, `mDocView.getDisplayedViewIndex()` but it gives me `NullPointerException` because page is not rendered yet.

Please suggest me.

Comment: did you get a solution to your issue?